# Endless loop with \PassOptionsToClass, \loadclass and koma script

Tags: koma-script, document-classes

I noticed that one of codes stopped working after an texlive update and runs into an endless loop somehow. I'm not certain why, but I narrowed it down to having something to do with `\PassOptionsToClass` and `\LoadClass` when used with koma script. I tested it with `scrartcl` and `scrreprt` which runs into an endless loop while `article` and `book`doesn't. To my surprise, `\LoadClassWithOptions` worked with koma script.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{setup.cls}
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}
    \LoadClass{scrartcl}
    %\LoadClassWithOptions{scrartcl}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{setup}

\begin{document}
    hello world
\end{document}
```

Comment: this has been already reported and is discussed here https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/580 and here https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/tickets/10/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer similar problem here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600152/3929

Comment: @daleif yes, saw it, just looking.

Comment: please try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600155/1090