# Twocolumn mod option in a class doesn't work any more

Tags: two-column, class-options

I'm using a class containing

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{class_test}
\LoadClassWithOptions{scrbook}
\ClassInfo{class_test}{Copyright (c), 2021.}
%--------------
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

In the main document, I have

```
\documentclass[
  french,
  a4paper,
  landscape,
  twocolumn,
  twoside       = false,
  numbers       = enddot,
  parskip       = half,
  fontsize      = 11,
  DIV           = 15
  ]{class_test}
%
%------------------
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

For a week, the two-column mode no longer displays correctly. Do you know why ?

[image]

Comment: Scrbook has dom issues. Have you tried without spaces around the =?

Comment: Yes, I get the same issue without the spaces, with `scrartcl`, `scrreprt`... But everything works fine without using any class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can use this, we'll sort something out

```
\makeatletter
\def\@pass@ptions#1#2#3{%
  \@expl@@@filehook@set@curr@file@@nNN
    {\@expl@@@filehook@resolve@file@subst@@w #3.#1\@nil}%
      \reserved@a\reserved@b
  \@expl@@@filehook@clear@replacement@flag@@
  \expandafter\xdef\csname opt@\reserved@a\endcsname{%
    \@ifundefined{opt@\reserved@a}\@empty
      {\csname opt@\reserved@a\endcsname,}%
    \zap@space#2 \@empty}%
  \expandafter\let
    \csname opt@#3.#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname opt@\reserved@a\endcsname
    \@ifundefined{@raw@opt@#3.#1}%
      {\expandafter\gdef\csname @raw@opt@#3.#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{#2}}%
      {\expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname @raw@opt@#3.#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\expandafter,#2}}%
}
\def\@loadwithoptions#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\let\csname opt@#3.#1\expandafter\endcsname
       \csname opt@\@currname.\@currext\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname @raw@opt@#3.#1\expandafter\endcsname
       \csname @raw@opt@\@currname.\@currext\endcsname
   #2{#3}}
\makeatother
\documentclass[
  french,
  a4paper,
  landscape,
  twocolumn,
  twoside       = false,
  numbers       = enddot,
  parskip       = half,
  fontsize      = 11,
  DIV           = 15
  ]{class_test}
%
%------------------
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```